# Where can I find some free benchmarks to evaluate a MCU?

Tags: floating-point, benchmarking

At present, I'm designing a soft processor with single-precision floating point unit (FPU). I am going to put my soft core into an FPGA and do some performance evaluation. The benchmarks are supposed to contain many single-precision floating point calculations, such as fadd, fmul, fdiv and fsqrt. Therefore, I can know the speed-up provided by FPU. Besides, I also want to compare my soft core with popular cores from ARM such as Cortex-M0, M1, M3. Since ARM provides `DesignStart` of these cores, it should be easy to put them into an FPGA and do comparision.

I only know 2 free benchmarks that could run on a soft core: Dhrystone and CoreMark. Can anyone share other free benchmarks for evaluation? Spending 1000+ dollars to buy a benchmark is not affordable for me.

Comment: This seems off-topic here, since you are basically looking for a software suite.